# Cannot import 'BaseHTTPRequestHandler'

Tags: python, server

I want to create a web server using    http.server module in Python. But when execute the code it shows an error    ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseHTTPRequestHandler'

I have Python27 and Python34 both installed on the same system.

Comment: how you installed your package and how you try to import it?

Comment: Most likely a conflict between 2.7/3.4 - have you tried uninstalling one or the other?

Comment: `http.server` is a 3.x thing.  You want [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) for 2.7.